# move img with same source name from variable

Tags: jquery, css

Am trying to move an image with the same source value when i click on its small image thumbnail but i don't know which is the right way. I tried using jquery's find() function but nothing is happening..

```
$('#slide1_controls img').click(function (event){
    var srcs=$(this).attr("src");
    $('#slide-frame').find("img[src=srcs]").animate({
         "left": "+=350px"
     }, {
         "queue": false,
             "duration": 1000
     }).animate({
         'opacity': '1'
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ang3lo0o/Fmsvx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to put the `srcs` variable into your `.find()`

```
$('#slide-frame').find("img[src='" + srcs + "']").animate({
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to tymeJV's answer, use better `.on()`

```
$('#slide1_controls img').on('click',function (event){
  var srcs=$(this).attr("src");
  $('#slide-frame').find("img[src='"+ srcs +"']").animate({
     "left": "+=350px"
  }, {
     "queue": false,
         "duration": 1000
  }).animate({
     'opacity': '1'
 });
});
```